# Decrement all values in a column after insert at top SQL

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

```
Before Inserting
Id Priority
1 . 1
2 . 2
3 . 3

After Inserting Id: 4, Priority 2
Id Priority
1 . 1
4 . 2
2 . 3
3 . 4
```

fairly new to postgres, and i have a table with a column named priority. this column should have unique values, and if you attempt to give a row a priority that already exists, it would basically insert it with that priority, and decrement all the priorities that are <= by one to accommodate it.

is there a term for this sort of behavior? i know it will involve a column with unique values, but are there any model constraints i can introduce to enable this sort of behavior? or do i need to manually code an algorithm to do this and account for all edge cases.

Comment: Curious if there is a more elegant answer to this than a trigger after insert updating priority = priority + 1 where priority +> inserted priority.

Comment: Seems like there is an ON CONFLICT model constraint that can update the row that has that unique value you are trying to insert. I wonder if this can be triggered successively? Insert at priority 3, priority 3 exists, update existing priority 3 to priority 4, priority 4 exists, update existing priorty 4 to priority 5, priority 5 exists...

Comment: Not sure how well that would cascade if you have more than a couple ID's being changed on insert.   I'll give an answer that calculates priority on the fly

Comment: specs call for only one priority to be updated/inserted at a time. seems like cascading triggers are designed for this sort of behavior, http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/05/database-triggers-encapsulation-and.html , now just to figure out if sequelize supports that

Comment: I meant if you had a database with priority 1 through 10001 and tried to insert priority 2...would the on conflict model constrain efficiently bump all 10k?  I'd suspect that solution would not scale very well and likely result in a giant On Conflict loop

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't store priority as it's own field.  Create the table as ID, priority, Date_entered.  Then use:

```
Select ID, rank() over (order by priority, date_entered) as priority
...
```

I suspect since the rank can change so frequently, calculating it on the fly like this would be preferential to attempting to store the rank and keep it updated.

edit:
There is a logical flaw to this that I can spot already...if record 4 was inserted as priority 2 (so the database contains 2 priority 2 records), there really wouldn't be an easy way to inject ID 5 between ID 4 and 2 without manipulating the date_entered field.

second edit:
Allowing the priority column to be decimal (priority 2 entered, then priority 2.5 entered, and so on), then using the rank() function to resolve that to an integer would get around that.   There isn't a pretty answer here that I can find